# why i can't persist object by openjpa? - incorrect validation

Tags: java, validation, annotations, bean-validation, openjpa

In my web applicaton I use OpenJPA on Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/7.0.37 server. I use Netbeans to auto generate class ("Entity Class from database..." and "Session Beans From Entity Class...").

my User.class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "User.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM User u"),
@NamedQuery(name = "User.findByIdUser", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.idUser = :idUser"),
@NamedQuery(name = "User.findByLogin", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.login = :login"),
@NamedQuery(name = "User.findByPassword", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.password = :password")})
public class User implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Basic(optional = false)
 @NotNull
 @Column(name = "id_user")
 private Short idUser;


 @Size(max = 8)
 @Column(name = "login")
 private String login;
 @Size(max = 64)
 @Column(name = "password")
 private String password;
 @JoinTable(name = "USER_has_ROLES", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_id", referencedColumnName = "id_user")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "ROLES_id", referencedColumnName = "id_roles")})
 @ManyToMany
 private List<Roles> rolesList;
 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
 private List<Lecturer> lecturerList;
 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
 private List<Student> studentList;

//constructors, getters, setters
}
```

when I create new user by ManagedBean:

```
private void addUser() {
    User user = new User();    
    user.setLogin(registerLog);
    user.setPassword(registerPass);
    Roles r = new Roles();  
    r.setIdRoles(new Short("2"));
    List<Roles> roleList = new ArrayList<Roles>();
    roleList.add(r);        
    user.setRolesList(roleList);    


    userFacade.create(user);  //<------here i create by abstract facade by em.persist(user);

}
```

i get exception:

```
javax.el.ELException: javax.ejb.EJBException: The bean encountered a non-application exception; nested exception is: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: A validation constraint failure occurred for class "model.entity.User".

viewId=/pages/register.xhtml
location=/home/jakub/Projekty/Collv2/build/web/pages/register.xhtml
phaseId=INVOKE_APPLICATION(5)

Caused by:
 javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException - A validation constraint failure occurred for class "model.entity.User".
at   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.validation.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:282)

/pages/register.xhtml at line 26 and column 104 action="#{registerController.register}"
```

it's look like I my user id is not correct. What is wrong ?

Comment: Figure out which constraint it is then? Do something like remove the properties from `User` one-by-one (except for `Id`) then see which one makes the error go away.

Comment: I try it and I know that have to be `@NotNull` annotation, because when i remove it and debug code it, there isn't stop at `em.persist(user)` but after that i get exception: `javax.el.ELException: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction was rolled back, presumably because setRollbackOnly was called during a synchronization` In database i haven't any information about added user

Comment: Is that all the output you're getting? There should be a cause for the rollback somewhere as well...

Comment: it is: `Caused by:
org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.SetRollbackOnlyException - setRollbackOnly() called. See stacktrace for origin
at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.setRollbackOnly(TransactionImpl.java:126)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is your id generation type - GenerationType.IDENTITY. Usually when using identity a special database column is used to generate the id. The id is not generated until the data is inserted into the database and the id itself is not available to the entity until after commit. However, Bean Validation occurs on the pre-persist callback using the current state of the entity. This will fail, because the id is still `null`.

I probably would just change the generation type.

Comment: I try every generation strategy (`GenerationType.AUTO, GenerationType.IDENTITY, GenerationType.SEQUENCE` and `GenerationType.TABLE`) but every time i get same exception: `javax.el.ELException: javax.ejb.EJBException: The bean encountered a non-application exception; nested exception is: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: A validation constraint failure occurred for class "model.entity.User".`

Comment: when i remove `@NotNull` annotation and set `GenerationType.IDENTITY` i get `javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException`.   When i set `GenerationType.AUTO`, `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` or `GenerationType.TABLE` it works but     do you think that i can remove `@NotNull` annotation ?

Answer (score 0):

I won't do this:

```
Roles r = new Roles();  
r.setIdRoles(new Short("2"));
List<Roles> roleList = new ArrayList<Roles>();
roleList.add(r);
```

This basically is a misused, if this Role is exist and able to link to User you're creating, you should retrieve it and set; otherwise, if you want to create a new Role, don't set @Id for it, or it will cause error as OpenJPA will look for an existing item instead of creating new one.

And, yes, it's possible the cause of your error. The fix is retrieve Role or just don't set @Id attribute. Plus, .setIdRoles() naming is quite strange naming to me.

Comment: ok, i changed above code to this: `Roles r = rolesFacade.find(new Short("2"));            
        List<Roles> roleList = new ArrayList<Roles>();
        roleList.add(r);
        user.setRolesList(roleList);` But it dosen't resolve my problem. Again i have the same exception with @NotNull (`javax.el.ELException: javax.ejb.EJBException: The bean encountered a non-application exception; nested exception is: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: A validation constraint failure occurred for class ...`) and without (`javax.el.ELException: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException...`)